# How to execute a web service in java with digest authentication?

Tags: java, json, web-services, digest-authentication

I want to execute a web service in java. Web service has implemented digest authentication.

Digest needs following variables: nonce, realm, qop, userName, password.

I tried following code but it throws 401 error:

```
URL url = new URL(str);
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");           
httpCon.setDoInput(true);
httpCon.setUseCaches(false);
httpCon.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Digest username='utoter1@cust1',     realm='Invene', nonce='MTM4MjQ0NzgTGE1NWJkNg==', qop=auth");

OutputStream outstream = httpCon.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(outstream);
out.write(jsnStr);
int httpResponceCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
String httpResponceMessage = httpCon.getResponseMessage();
```

Please guide me thru the problem.

Comment: any comment? plz have a look at this problem.

Comment: **Have I posted this query in wrong section!!** Wondering why there is no reply. Plz reply.